# Present NFS to multiple projects

Tags: openshift, kubernetes, openshift-origin

I have one NFS mount containing some read only media assets that I want to present to multiple projects.

Creating a new PV in each project with the same NFS path seems too clunky. What if other PVCs were to claim my asset directory by accident?

Other than that I've got no clue how to do this. How can I accomplish this?

edit: To be clear - I want to avoid cluster-admin intervention. Cluster admin rights are required when creating a PV.

**PV CONFIG**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: my_app
  name: my-assets
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 25Gi
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: my-assets
    namespace: my_namespace
    resourceVersion: "13480134"
    uid: ea36d352-1a22-11e7-a443-0050568b4a96
  nfs:
    path: /nfs_volume
    server: nfs_server
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
status: {}
```

PVCs from namespaces other than my_namespace cannot claim against this pv. Here's a PVC config from a different namespace that is unable to claim against the existing PV with `ReadWriteMany` .

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: my-assets
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 25Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my_app
  volumeName: my-assets
status: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by project, but if you are referring to `Deployments` of different apps it should work with a single PV definition for a NFS that has type `ReadWriteMany`. However I would recommend to always include one PV and PVC definition per deployment that requires access to the NFS. That way it is explicit from the deployment and you can change it for every app separately. Just imagine you want to change it for one app but not the other.

Here is an example that I use for an amazon EFS NFS mounting to all PODs in my CockroachDB deployment for writing backups. I have it split up into 2 yamls but you can also collapse them into one file. Note that you can use the same PersistentVolumeClaim for all PODs.

1 cockroachdbPV.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: cockroachdbpv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: {amazon path here}
    path: "/"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: cockroachdbpv
spec:
  accessModes:
    - "ReadWriteMany"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

2 cockroachdb.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cockroachdb
spec:
  serviceName: "cockroachdb"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cockroachdb
      annotations:
        {...}        
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cockroachdb
        {...}
        volumes:
        {...}
        - name: efsdir
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: cockroachdbpv
```

Comment: I think the kubernetes equivalent of "project" is "namespace"
I see your point with the 1 PV per namespace, but my plan was to change selectors for different environments (Dev Test Prod). I'm still unable to make multiple claims against 1 PV across namespaces which I thought should be possible. (see edits for configs)

Comment: Yes, that is the normal behavior. You should be able to reuse the Persistent Volume Claim by using the same "claimName" in all the Deployments/StatefulSets where you need access (as in my example - that is why I deploy the PV together with the PVC in a single file).

Comment: Ok so back to the question... does that mean it's not possible to make multiple PVC claims against the same PV?

Comment: To be clear - I want to avoid cluster-admin intervention. Cluster admin rights are required when creating a PV.

Comment: But you would always use a cluster admin to deploy a new app in the new namespace? So the PV/PVC definition could be part of that?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to list `ReadWriteMany` as an [access mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) in the PV definition and in PVCs as well.

There is an example available here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/volumes/nfs

Comment: see edits. PVs are defined as `ReadWriteMany` - still unable to claim across different namespaces

Comment: I see. Unfortunately for you PersistentVolume is a namespaced object. It's not possible to create a PVC against it from a different namespace - this is working as intended and won't be fixed.